# map vim leader key to backspace

Tags: vim, backspace, leader

The vim documention on how to set the default leader key ( `:h mapleader`) provides one simple example:

```
:let mapleader = ","
```

I want to map it to backspace and tried a bunch of options, this being the first one:

```
:let mapleader="<BS>"
```

But nothing seemed to work.

Answer (score 4):

To make it work I had to use:

```
:let mapleader="\<BS>"
```

Another option is to not override the default `\` leader key, but map backspace to it, effectively ending up with two simultaneous leader keys:

```
map <BS> <Leader>
```